# When to use @IncludeEngines and when to use@ExtendWith of Junit5

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, build.gradle, junit5, spring-boot-test

Please support me in understanding and over coming confusion of when to use
`@IncludeEngines` and when to use `@ExtendWith` in JUnit 5.

Apologies if this question is too basic.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ExtendWith` is used to register custom [extensions](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions)

In terms of JUnit4 constructs: `@RunWith`, `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` have all been superseded by `@ExtendWith`. Although JUnit 5 does retain [limited support for rules](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-rule-support), the JUnit team's strong advice is to move to using `@ExtendWith`.

There are examples of some common JUnit4 rules re-implemented as JUnit5 extensions [here](https://github.com/glytching/junit-extensions).

`@IncludeEngines` specifies the `org.junit.platform.engine.TestEngine` implementation(s) to be included when running a test suite on the JUnit Platform. Although this is in `org.junit.platform.suite.api` and is therefore available for developers to use, I can't think of any situation in which you'd need to use it. It could be used to engage a specific engine e.g. the vintage engine rather than the `JupiterTestEngine` but that would imply a need to run tests in a JUnit4 environment and this can be achieved using `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`.

Do you *think* you need to use `@IncludeEngines`? If so, I'd suggest explaining why you think you need to use it and you might find that there are other ways to use JUnit5 which doe not require use of `@IncludeEngines`.

Comment: like glytching said,  we sometimes need to use @IncludeEngines to execute test with engine like cucumber engine

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#suites-with-different-configurations